# Java code not returning the proper table from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this testing code that im trying to use to print the result set from my database table in MySQL. Right now It is printing the following.

```
Connecting database...
Database connected!
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl@6f5f1a42
```

I am not sure why it is not printing the table columns and values in my db.

here is the code.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

class Test {

public static void main (String [] args) throws SQLException {
    //   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqldb

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqldb?useSSL=false";
    String username = "joker";
    String password = "joker";

    System.out.println("Connecting database...");
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.println("Database connected!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
    }

    Statement stmt = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * FROM pet");


    System.out.println(rs.getStatement().toString());

    stmt.close();


    close(connection);


}

public static void close(Connection con){
    if(con != null){
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

After your execute query, you should do something like this

```
while (rs.next()) { 
 System.out.println(rs.getInt("column name");)}
```

Change get operation by column data type. exp: rs.getString, rs.getDouble etc.

check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) for further information

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, the [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) merely represents the returned data:

> A table of data representing a database result set, which is usually
>   generated by executing a statement that queries the database.
>
> A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of
>   data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The
>   next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns
>   false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be
>   used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.

As such, you need to iterate through the result set if you are interested in the data returned from your query using the respective getters such as `getString` or `getInt`:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getInt("Id"));
    System.out.println(rs.getString("Name"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over ResultSet

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("Col1")); // or rs.getString(0);
    System.out.println(rs.getString("Col2"));
    System.out.println(rs.getString("ColN"));
}
```

Comment: int i=0;
     while (rs.next()) {
         System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + "\t"); // or rs.getString(0);
         System.out.print(rs.getString(i)+ "\t");
         System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
         i++;
     } Will this work as well?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Pay attention to column type. If a column is Integer, then you have to do this `rs.getInt(i)`

Answer (score 0):

The output `com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl@6f5f1a42` looks like the output of the default `toString` method inherited from the `Object` class. This is what gets invoked if the `ResultSet` class you're using doesn't implement its own `toString` method.

To print out rows and columns, you're going to have to iterate over the result set yourself. For example:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getXXX(...));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the column names please use the below code

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++ ) {
  String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
}
```

Similarly you may also fetch the data by either providing column number or name in a loop

```
ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
try {
  while (rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt(1);
    String userName = rs.getString(2);
    String firstName = rs.getString(3);
    String surname = rs.getString(4);
    Timestamp timeReg = rs.getTimestamp(5);
    // ... do something with these variables ...
  }
} finally {
  rs.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First up all you have to load the  JDBC Driver Class using Class.forName(). 
Class.forName() load a given Java class in JVM and it also exit in your classpath.
the complete synatx is just like:- Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: I never did that but I'm still getting a connection to the database. I did add the jdbc to the buildpath in eclipse

Comment: @camel-man When you load a JDBC Driver Class , driver would have some JDBC specific settings to be executed as a very first step of Java Database Access Logic, it is also known as driver registration.So without registration of driver the inserting is not possible. So use it at the very first line in the try block.

Comment: Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName(). Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using Class.forName() will continue to work without modification. 

 When the method getConnection is called, the DriverManager will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application.